# Dimension problem when continue training the pre-trained data

Tags: dimension, pre-trained-model

i want to load a pre-trained h5 file which i let train in python. But when i load the file and try to train with same training command, it has a dimension problem. The input dimensions are 3 and output dimension is 1.

```
new_model=load_model("model-020-virtuell-test.h5")
score = new_model.evaluate(X_valid, y_valid, verbose=0)
print('Test loss 1:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy 1:', score[1])
#assert_allclose(model.predict(X_train),
#            new_model.predict(X_train),
#            1e-5)
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath,
                             monitor='val_loss',
                             verbose=0,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             mode='auto')

history = new_model.fit_generator(batcher(data_dir, X_train, y_train, batch_size, True),
                    samples_per_epoch,
                    nb_epoch,
                    max_q_size=1,
                    validation_data=batcher(data_dir, X_valid, y_valid, batch_size, False),
                    nb_val_samples=len(X_valid),
                    callbacks=[checkpoint],
                    verbose=1)
```

and i got an error message that the lambda input has 4 dimensions but got array(2786,1).

The training has done without problem with this code.

I added only load_model line and wanted to train this model continue.

What should i change in this case?

Thank you in advance.